# How do I call a class using a key listener?

Tags: java, keylistener

I am trying to have a window pop up when key 1 is pressed and a separate window when key 2 is pressed.

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {

          if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1)
        {
          TicTacToeDriver tic = new TicTacToeDriver();
          PointCounter();
        }

        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2)
        {
            HangmanDriver hang = new HangmanDriver();
            PointCounter();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
```

The tic tac toe and hangman games were created by two separate people and the programmers created their own driver.

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: e.getKeyChar() == '1' and e.getKeyChar() == '2' ? Is that what you want?

Comment: When I run the program and press 1 the tic tac toe game does not appear, but the counter does. How do I make the tic tac toe game appear?

Comment: Maybe `.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I am assuming that the programmers are familiar with java oriented programming...

Thus, You would just create a new object of one of the games.

```
Hangman h = new Hangman();
or
Tick h = new Tick();
Tick.start() //depending on their code.
```

If you are running a Jframe...
     you would need to

```
(insert object name).setVisible(true);
```

Since you mentioned that they have drivers I assume that they use main methods instead of constructors even though the code you provided creates objects of the classes.

Thus, when the button is clicked or key is pressed.. Just call the main method of the driver class.

```
   hangman.main(null); //this is a terrible way to do it btw.
```

I also recommend using KeyBindings API instead of keylistener as keybindings does not require focus... which could also be problem.

Another problem would be..

this.addKeyListener(this);

You have to add the keylistener to the component.
But, this is where problems arise as you are using keylistener.. Your JComponent that you added the KeyListener to might not have focus. Thus, the action wont fire till the component has focus and an action is triggered.